# AppVersion.getVersionNumber is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the app version of my ionic-cordova app after installing the  [app version plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version) 
 but when i try to use the function i get the following error
[image]

Here is my code that calls the `.getVersionNumber` function

```
this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then((version) => {
                alert(version);
            });
```

I tried running npm update to see if it might be a dependency issue but no luck there. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

**I also imported app version and injected it in my constructor**
[image]

[image]

I also added AppVersion to my app.module.ts file

```
providers: [
        AppVersion
    ]
```

I also ran an npm prune to see if any appversion had any tied dependency i had to install but i had the corresponding dependencies so no luck there either

Comment: what ionic version are you using?

Comment: @AJT_82 i am running ionic-angular 3.9.2

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. You are using plugin that is meant for ionic4 (all imports ends with `ngx`). You should look at the v3 documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-version/

Comment: @AJT_82 thank you, extremely appreciated